# What causes running coupling constants to converge to one value at high energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, supersymmetry, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

In [this](https://www.physicsmasterclasses.org/exercises/keyhole/en/projects/running_alphas.html#:%7E:text=The%20running%20coupling%20constants.,get%20closer%20and%20closer%20together.) article ("The coupling constants and unification of interactions", sicsmasterclasses.org) we can read:

> The running coupling constants. Scientists believe that as they push the energy they are able to study higher and higher (achieving smaller and smaller resolution), they will see the values of the coupling constants get closer and closer together.

A diagram from the same article:

[image]

I read: "scientists **believe"**. What? Believe? Do they vary the coupling by hand? I can imagine that there is a screening effect, a dressing of particles, renormalisation, and all that, but why should a vertex factor of, say the EM radiation become the same as that of the weak (which **could** be a residue force) or color force, or even gravity?
Note that in the above diagram, they don't meet at a common point. To make them meet one needs to invoke supersymmetry. Supersymmetry though seems more and more unlikely, as boundaries are pushed.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: This topic is largely work-in-progress, so physicists can make an educated guess about the result, based on "reasonable assumptions" or the fact that it should connect smoothly with other, better known theories. This "educated guess" is what "scientists believe" mean in this context, I think.

Comment: @Miyase So the diagram is based on belief. How is a running coupling made dependent on energy and momentum? How is the functional dependency established?

Comment: An educated guess based on a theoretical model and extrapolation isn't a mere "belief". Renormalization group does give solid results about the dependence of coupling constants with energy.

Comment: @Miyase That's true, but RG is connected with dressing up of particles. And a naked particle is thought to have a very different coupling than a dressed up one.  So in fact all couplings are constant but differently dressed up. But why all constants (infinities?) are the same?

Comment: As far as I know, the "infinite" values of those constants aren't considered physical, they only show that we're working with effective theories, and that at some point we're hitting a validity limit.

Comment: @Miyase Can't these infinities be avoided by giving particles a size in three extra space dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about the specific plot in question, since the link does not work for me but the thesis [M. Lautsch, 2014, Running Couplings in the Standard Model and their Implications to possible Physics beyond the Standard Model](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1336548) discusses this. Figure 1 of this thesis [image: Fig. 1 of M. Lautsch's thesis] is almost identical to the one in OP's question. The solid lines are the one loop running couplings of the standard model. The beta functions are used to compute running couplings (see Eqs. (67 -(69) in Sec. 4.3 of the thesis):
$$
\begin{align}
U(1):&\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial\ln(p/M)} \alpha_1^{-1} = -\frac{41}{20\pi},\\
SU(2):&\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial\ln(p/M)} \alpha_2^{-1} = \frac{19}{12\pi},\\
SU(3):&\qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial\ln(p/M)} \alpha_3^{-1} = \frac{7}{2\pi}.
\end{align}
$$
and for the plots the experimental starting values of $\alpha_1^{-1}=59.66$, $\alpha_2^{-1}=29.58$, and $\alpha_3^{-1}=8.446$ are used at $M=M_Z=91.1876\,\mathrm{GeV}$ (see Secs. 2.3 and 4.3 of the thesis).

As already mentioned in the question: for the one loop beta functions of the standard model the couplings only meet in a relatively large region, while supersymmetric extensions meet basically in a point.

One can do the same using two loop beta functions (see Fig. 2 of Lautsch's thesis):
[image: Fig. 2 of M. Lautsch's thesis].

This is what people apparently do when generating such graphs: I do not really want to comment on how much "believing" or "educated guessing" is involved here but I think the perturbative computations for the running couplings seem to be legit. Wether or not perturbative computations are valid over those energy ranges is another question: The one and two loop results differ quite a bit in terms of magnitude but not in terms of the overlap region.

Comment: Is the "naked" coupling infinite?

Comment: There are multiple couplings involved and for details on the couplings/their respective counter terms have a look in the paper but if you consider the “naked” coupling as a running coupling without appropriate counter terms then yes there are divergent momentum integrals involved. When treating these with renormalization/counter terms the results at one-loop are scheme independent but beyond one-loop one should use a unified scheme for all (as done in the thesis since they use dimensional regularization).